# Jenkins 2.0 docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-image

Is there a docker image for `Jenkins 2.0`?

This article on cloudbees was written in 2016 and I believe things have changed a lot since then. (https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/get-started-jenkins-20-docker)

I was browsing Jenkins repo at https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/ which has a tag `2.130`. Is it just a newer release of `Jenkins 2.0`?

I am looking for `Jenkins` with Pipeline support.

Comment: 2.130 is the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest Jenkins has pipeline support. It is available as a Docker container, according to [here](https://jenkins.io/download/). The Docker link on that page points to [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/), the same link you mentioned in your question. So give it a try!

Details:

- Long-term support (LTS) Docker container version: 2.121.1
- Weekly Docker container version: 2.130